# Javascript syntax of functions signature

Tags: javascript

In the documentation of styled from [MUI](https://mui.com/system/styled/), I came across this function signature:

```
styled(Component, [options])(styles) => Component
```

I found many examples with this syntax in the [MUI demos](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#MiniDrawer.js).

It seams to me, I am lacking basic syntax knowledge, because I don't get the `(styles) => Component` part. I understand this is a lambda expression, but for me it's not part of the function signature, because it's not enclosed into the parenthesis.

Can someone explain, what it does and why it's different form a signature like

```
styled(Component, [options], (styles) => Component)
```

?

Comment: That documentation could be a bit clearer, :-) not least because it never says what `styles` is. But Quentin's answer below is correct (as is almost always the case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> styled(Component, [options])(styles) => Component
> ```

If you're not familiar with the syntax used in that part of the documentation, then the example after the description is excellent.

`styled` is a function which takes two arguments (`Component` and, optionally, `options`).

It returns a function.

The returned function takes one argument (`styles`) and returns a `Component`.

---

Your version, by contrast:

> ```
> styled(Component, [options], (styles) => Component)
> ```

Here, `styled` is a function which takes three arguments.

- `Component`
- `options` (which is marked as optional, but can't be because the third  argument isn't marked as optional)
- A function which takes one argument (`styles`) and returns a `Component`

The return value for `styled` is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still found it confusing. There is no dot ? Probably because it doesn't return an object. So it's an anonymous function ?

Comment: Well, functions are objects … but the value you care about is the function itself, and not a property of it. An anonymous function is one which doesn't have a name (you seem to think it is one that is not assigned to a variable in the current scope) and I've no idea if the return function has a name or not (it matters little unless you're examining it in a stacktrace). You could easily assign it to a variable. `const myCustomComponentStylingFunction = styled(CustomComponent); const  StyledCustomComponent = myCustomComponentStylingFunction({color: "red"})`.

Comment: https://javascript.info/currying-partials is probably worth a read for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an API description syntax, not actual JS code, where '=>' is used to describes what type of value is returned from the function (in this case an object of type Component). It's a bit confusing because it looks like a regular JS arrow function. The syntax before the arrow however is valid JS Code and describes a self invoking function. `styled` returns a function that can be immediately invoked by adding parentheses to the function call.

```js
// example implementation of styled
const styled = function(component, options = {}) {
 return function(styles) {return new Component(styles)};
}

// long version of API description
const returnedFunction = styled(myComponent, options);
const returnedComponent = returnedFunction(styles);

// condensed version
const returnedComponent = styled(MyComponent)(styles);
```

Your provided example would not work, because your arrow function would be executed before the actual function call and only its return value (in your case Component) would be passed as third argument, the `styles` argument of the callback function itself would have no impact.